# Android: how to Send the current time/date directly to the webserver when user click on the item

Tags: android, datetime, listview, android-activity, clock

I created a listview with diff. activity to each items. When the user click on "clock in" I would like to grab the current time/date and send that data to the webserver in quickest way possible (without going through 2 step process to confirm). This will be for secondActivity class.

UPDATE* I am planning to add a password to the time/date within the phone so the user cant change them. I prefer current time/date within the phone instead of server time because if theres no signal/reception theres no way to clock in. How can I be able to grab the current time/date within the phone?

Customer.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Customer extends ListActivity
{
    TextView selection;
    String[] items = { "Start Trip", "Clock in", "Customer Svc", 
            "Independent Inspection", "Pick Up", "Log Out" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

private static final int ACTIVITY_0 = 0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;
private static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 2;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
    switch (position)
    {
        case ACTIVITY_0:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.IntentIntegrator.class);
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_1:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_2:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Pass the item position as the requestCode parameter, so on the `Activity`'s
    // return you can examine it, and determine which activity were you in prior. 
    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Perform different actions based on from which activity is
        // the application returning:
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case ACTIVITY_0:
                // contents contains whatever the code was
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                // Handle successful scan. In this example 
                // I just put the results into the TextView
                resultsTxt.setText(format + "\n" + contents);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_1:
                // TODO: handle the return of the SecondActivity
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_2:
                // TODO: handle the return of the ThirdActivity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' 
        // before a code is scanned.
        resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the quickest way would be creating a new thread and opening a connection to the server.

Take a look to the code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/?data="+System.currentTimeMillis());

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //if there is no need to read the content then we close the connection

        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}).start();
```

Then on your server-side you've to read the $_GET['data'] variable if you're working with php.

Please consider that this solution is not ok for different timezones. I would probably rely on server-side date.

Comment: I think that would be good idea to use the server time instead of the phone time which a user can take advantage and change the time themselves. Can you give me more detail on how to put that together within the customer.java that will link to only 'clock in' item?

Comment: I realized what if the user is in the area with no signal they wont be able to communicate with the server. I think it would be better risk to grab the time/date within the phone.

Comment: I am planning to add a password to the time/date within the phone so the user cant change them. I prefer current time/date within the phone instead of server time because if theres no signal/reception theres no way to clock in. How can I be able to grab the current time/date within the phone?

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to grab the current time & date from the device itself (i was able to lock the time/date settings) and send it to the server (or store in phone and attempt to send when reception is available).? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using Time:

```
    Time timeToday = new Time();
    timeToday.setToNow();
    today = timeToday.year+"-"+ timeToday.MONTH+"-"+timeToday.monthDay;
```

Comment: I would like a sample code where I can click on the 'clock in' item and it will grab that current time/date and send it out to the webserver. Do you suggest making another class which would be secondActivity or code in within Customer.java just for 'clock in' onclickitem

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to grab the current time & date from the device itself (i was able to lock the time/date settings) and send it to the server (or store in phone and attempt to send when reception is available).? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why rely on the time from a users device? What if I changed the time on my handset then clocked in? How are you going to handle different timezones?

Why not simply rely on server time of the webserver since you know you can depend on this and you're already making a call to the webserver?

Comment: I didn't realized a user can changed the time and take advantage of that. I will be using the server time of the webserver now.

Comment: I realized what if the user is in the area with no signal it wont be able to communicate with the server. I think it would be better risk to grab the time/date within the phone.

Comment: I am planning to add a password to the time/date within the phone so the user cant change them. I prefer current time/date within the phone instead of server time because if theres no signal/reception theres no way to clock in. How can I be able to grab the current time/date within the phone?

Comment: You can't "add a password" to stop a user changing the data/time of their device, given that it's their device and all...

Comment: Can you give me a sample code to grab the current time & date from the device itself (i was able to lock the time/date settings) and send it to the server (or store in phone and attempt to send when reception is available).? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this to get current date and time:

```
    private String getDateandTime() {
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
       Log.e("Activity name", "time date "+formattedDate);
       return formattedDate;
   }
```

And call this function when user clicks to button and send this to server using networking library like Volley or Retrofit.